# C++ executable crashing

Tags: c++

I am starting to create a binary tree. So far all I have added is an insert function and I believe it works fine. When I compile my application, header and implementation files together it produces a executable but with an error code above it about exception handler used.... When I go to run the executable it crashes. I don't understand why it is crashing, can someone please help! Thanks in advance.

The command line errors http://gyazo.com/7ca1e8fb1a66da39e927e9ba627d3f53

My application file called mainprogramming.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Rndnums[10] = {3, 99, 76, 49, 32, 9, 77, 64, 81, 24};

    BinaryTree *tree = new BinaryTree();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tree->insert(Rndnums[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My header file called Header.h

```
class BinaryTree
{
// Can only be accessed by the class itself
private:
    struct node
    {
        // Data stored in this node of he tree
        int data;
        // The left branch of the tree
        node *left;
        // The right branch of the tree
        node *right;
    };

    node *tree;
    void insert(node *tree, int value);

// Can be accessed by all
public:
    BinaryTree(){};
    ~BinaryTree();
    void insert(int value);

};
```

My implementation file called implementation.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

// Inserts a value into the tree - notice **
void BinaryTree::insert(node *tree, int value)
{
    // Check if nullptr. If so set new node
    if (tree == nullptr)
    {
        // Create new node
        tree = new node;
        // Set new value
        tree->data = value;
        // Set branches to nullptr
        tree->left = nullptr;
        tree->right = nullptr;
    }
    // If the input value is less than the node in the tree
    else if(value < tree->data)
    {
        insert(tree->left, value);
        cout << "The value " << value << "has been added as a left child\n";
    }
    // If the input value is greater than the node in the tree
    else if(value > tree->data)
    {
        insert(tree->right, value);
        cout << "The value " << value << "has been added as a right child\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The value " << value << "can only be equal and must already exist in the tree\n";
    }
}

void BinaryTree::insert(int value)
{
    insert(this->tree, value);
    cout << "It ran";
}
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, and stepped through each statement, which statement is causing the issue?

Comment: No where in you code do you set `tree` to `nullptr` so `if (tree == nullptr)` wont work on the first iteration.

Comment: Not sure which statement is causing and issue and how would I solve that issue then?

Comment: Say if I add in at the top of my implementation.cpp BinaryTree::BinaryTree()
{
 tree = nullptr;
} will that solve my problem?

Comment: Always show exact error messages here, not using external sites.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your insert call:

```
void BinaryTree::insert(node * leaf_head, int value)
{
    ...
}
```

You are copying the pointer address then trying to create an object in that memory space, and then modifying that object.  It works fine when you change it to a reference to that pointer:

```
void BinaryTree::insert(node * & leaf_head, int value)
{
    ...
}
```

That way you are actually modifying the `tree` pointer within `BinaryTree` instead of a copy of it.

Comment: For the case where `value < tree->data` and `tree->left == nullptr`. `insert(tree->left, value)` is the same as `insert(nullptr, value)` so it is never really inserted into the tree. Passing by reference means the pointer `tree->left` is updated in the call so `tree->left != nullptr` when the call is done it points to the newly created node.

Comment: @rpattiso ahh I see whats going on now, thank you.

Comment: Right I tried what you posted and it didn't seem to work. I did what Nathan suggested in another comment and add in BinaryTree::BinaryTree() { tree = nullptr; } at the top of my implementation file. For this to work you I had to remove the {} beside BinaryTree(){}; in my header file. It now runs but I dont think its passing in the numbers....

Comment: Doesn't matter, managed to get the numbers in, I had to add another statement.

Comment: @CalumTempleton and what statement is that? When I changed your pointer to a reference it worked for me and created the tree.

Comment: basically that fix the bug but not the design problem that introduced the bug :D.. amazing because that tecnically address the question +1 for spreading abuse of reference to pointers.

Comment: @DarioOO hah yeah.  I was just answering the question, having to resort to a refrence to a pointer is definitely gross.

Comment: BinaryTree::BinaryTree()
{
 tree = nullptr;
}

// Inserts a value into the tree - notice **
void BinaryTree::insert(node *tree, int value)
{
 // Check if nullptr. If so set new node
 if (tree == nullptr)
 {
  // Create new node
  tree = new node;
  // Set new value
  tree->data = value;
  cout << "A new node has been set\n";
  // Set branches to nullptr
  tree->left = nullptr;
  tree->right = nullptr;
 }

Comment: // If the input value is less than the node in the tree
 if(tree != nullptr)
 {
  if(value < tree->data)
  {
   insert(tree->left, value);
   cout << "The value " << value << "has been added as a left child\n";
  }
  // If the input value is greater than the node in the tree
  else if(value > tree->data)
  {
   insert(tree->right, value);
   cout << "The value " << value << "has been added as a right child\n";
  }
  else
  {
   cout << "The value " << value << " can only be equal and must already exist in the tree\n";
  }
 }
}

Comment: Right I made some changes but something is not right with my pointer cause its now saying all the values are equal and going to the last statement...